# Include pointers in array of pointers in Parse Javascript query

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I know how to load the objects pointed in a pointer array in Parse (thanks to this link: https://www.parse.com/questions/include-pointer-in-array-of-pointers). However, I need to load objects pointed inside the array of pointers, too (which would be something equivalent to triple JOINs in SQL). I am querying a class that has an array of pointers, this works:

`query.include("myArrayColumn.pointer");`

It loads all the `Post` objects that are pointed inside the array. However, these `Post` object also have a `_User` pointer, and I need to get that `_User` object, too. I've tried:

`query.include("myArrayColumn.pointer.user");`

Unfortunatelly, user objects aren't fetched. Their id's are there, but trying to access anything other than `id` (e.g. username) returns undefined.

Is there a way to eager-load the users, or do I have to use a second query (or some other mechanism)?